# Serialize and Deserialize interface with Jackson (convert to a type that has the JSON annotation)

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, deserialization

When I run this code:

```
public void serialize(someInterface i, OutputStream o) throws Exception {
    if(i == null || o == null){
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.writeValue(o, i);
}
```

I get this error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of, problem: abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or be instantiated with additional type information
```

I am trying to serialize and deserialize the interface i. I know that I have to convert it to a different type that has the JSON annotation. So that Jackson would be able to read it. But I don't know how to to that.

I want to do this without modifying the interface. With code like:

```
@JsonSerialize(as=someInterface.class)
```

Comment: Is there any other annotation in the Interface class?! do you have any JsonSubTypes?!